# Does every activity has a DVM instance or every apk has a DVM instance?

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

Does every activity has a DVM instance or every apk has a DVM instance?
An apk can have multiple activities within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [What is Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) on the dev site:

> Every Android application runs in its
>   own process, with its own instance of
>   the Dalvik virtual machine.

So, each running application has it's own DVM instance and as you rightly say, that application may have multiple activities, but each of those activities will run in the Dalvik instance that started the application.

Comment: To add to this: The application will run on the Main thread (AKA, the UI Thread), the Activities will take their turn to run on this thread. An article explaining UI thread can be found here : http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-1-ui.html

Comment: Url does not contains the quote of `Every Android application runs in its own process, with its own instance of the Dalvik virtual machine.`
You need to Update this Url